# Define module parent item to contain other module items

Tags: routes

I want to define section of items in administrative area, for my custom module operations.

I defined some items with hook_menu in /admin/config/development/
But i would like now to make a section, that will containt those menu items, so on click on that parent item i would be presented with those "contained" items.

It is like, when you have admin/, you click Configuration and you get to the screen with all the items contained ( admin/config/ ).

It is probably very simple, but somehow could not trample on it!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is really simple. You need not use any additional code. You just need to follow the correct menu structure. I've posted a sample code below

```
     function mymodule_menu() {
      $items['admin/config/development/mymodule'] = array(
      //Your code here
      );
     $items['admin/config/development/mymodule/sub-module-1'] = array(
      //Your code here
      );
     $items['admin/config/development/mymodule/sub-module-2'] = array(
      //Your code here
      );
      return $items;

}
```

You need to clear the cache. Sometimes you might need to disable and re-enable your modules to register the menu. Now when you click `mymodule` menu item, a list of all your sub modules will be displayed.

Comment: I trust you :) I was trying the approach you propose before your posting,  but somehow i did not get it right ... ill try again carefully, im sure in success! Thanks!